# Append data from multiple xls files into one using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to achieve the following using a VBA macro:

- I have multiple .xls files, all of which have just one sheet
- In my macro, I want to append all the data from the other files into one sheet, by appending them at the bottom of the document behind each other. I have figured out the iterating through files, but copying and appending data is what is bugging me.

The code I have until now is as follows (missing parts are described within the comments)

```
Sub Iterate_Files()

Dim Fso As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim FileInFolder As Object

FromPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFolder = Fso.GetFolder(FromPath)

For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    For Each FileInFolder In objSubFolder.Files
    'Copy the data from sheet one of the FileInFolder
    'to the end of sheet in this file :/
    Next FileInFolder
Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Your journey has just begun!!  SO questions should pertain to debugging existing code not asking to have a 12 step process written for you.  I think that this site is what you are looking for: [Upwork.Com](https://www.upwork.com/)

Comment: lol what a way to make a commercial dude. I found the answer myself and I was missing 3 lines of code.

Comment: Care to either close the question then or update with your solution for others in case they have a similar question - and this one is asked a lot

Answer (score 0):

The following code appears to have solved the problem:

```
Sub Iterate_Files()

Dim Fso As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim FileInFolder As Object

FromPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFolder = Fso.GetFolder(FromPath)
Set TargetWb = ActiveWorkbook

R = 0
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    For Each FileInFolder In objSubFolder.Files
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FileInFolder)
        wbSource.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=TargetWb.Worksheets(2).Cells(R + 1, 1)
        R = R + 15
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next FileInFolder
Next objSubFolder

End Sub

Private Sub Rokaj_Click()
    Iterate_Files
End Sub
```